# what's the normal vector of plane doesn't cross origin

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^3$, one might find their normal vector $n:=x \times y$ via a cross product.
But then the cross product is only applicable to planes that cross the origin. What about planes that don't cross the origin, how can one find the normal vectors? For example, we translate the $x, y$ plane via adding another vector $z \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Would the resulting normal vector just be $z + x \times y$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a plane does not pass through the origin, you can translate it so that it does. The normal vectors to the two planes are the same. Notice that if you have the plane $x+y+2z=0$, its normal vector is $\vec n = (1,1,2)$. If I take the plane $x+y+2z=3$, it is parallel, and so the normal must be in the same direction. This does *not* mean that the normal vector is orthogonal to the vectors *from the origin* to points in the plane; it means that it is orthogonal to vectors lying in the plane. This means that if we take $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ (for example, $(0,1,1)$) in the plane, then
$$\vec n\cdot [(x,y,z)-(x_0,y_0,z_0)] = 0,$$
which is the same as saying
$$\vec n\cdot (x,y,z) = \vec n\cdot (x_0,y_0,z_0) = 3,$$
in our case.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, basically, the normal vectors would still be the same even with a displacement $z$, but i can only use it via offset first? I'm using the normal vector to test with other points in the original frame, that if all of them are on the same side. is there any way to use the normal vector without shitting the coordinate system?

Comment: You really need your origin *in* the plane, or else you have to shift every vector, as I indicated, by a known point in the plane.

Answer (score 0):

You might want the foot of the vector to be at $z$ (so it is a [free vector](https://www.citycollegiate.com/vectorXIf.htm)), but the direction will still be $x \times y$.

Comment: with displacement $z$, the new normal vector becomes $z + x \times y$ ?

Comment: @pengyu You are conflating free vectors and positional vectors.